# Change the Simple Facebook Connect popup position

Tags: plugins, facebook

**Is it possible to add a parameter to  Simple Facebook Connect and the sfc_like_button function to cause the popup to fly out to the left?**

Right now, it flies out to the right and is underneath the dark outer wrapper of my page.  *(see below)*

This happens in Firefox, IE and Safari. Using `overflow:visible` in the containing `div` doesn't help.

I've tried using positioning and z-index in that div and containing elements to position the popup on top of the wrapper with no luck.

Is this a function of the output of the iFrame at Facebook that can't be changed?

[image: screenshot]

This is the function that includes SFC:

```
<?php sfc_like_button(array('width' => '125', 'height' => '20', 'layout' => 'button_count')); ?>
```

This is the resulting html in page source:

```
<fb:like href='http://mydomain.com/page/' send='false' layout='button_count' show_faces='true' width='125' height='20' action='like' colorscheme='light' font='lucida+grande'></fb:like>
```

Comment: The DIV in which contains the fly-out needs a position, i.e. position:relative; in order for the z-index to work on any child elements. You should also give the child element a position to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10471848/css-z-index-overflow-facebook-xfbml-and-safari

Turns out I needed positions and z-indexes, but also this on the containing `<div>`, which uses a "clearfix" trick (instead of using overflow:hidden) to make #main wrap its floated children:

Original:

```
#main {
clear: both;
padding: 5px 0 0 0;
position: relative;
z-index:1;
overflow:hidden  /*removed */
}
```

Added:

```
#main:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  zoom: 1;
}
```